# Index of imprimitivity = Period of a matrix?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, nonnegative-matrices

I am learning about the theory of non-negative matrices and trying to connect and reconcile various definitions I came across.

The **index of imprimitivity** of an irreducible non-negative matrix $\boldsymbol{A}\geq0$ is denoted as $h_{\boldsymbol{A}}$ and defined as the number of its eigenvalues on the spectral circle.

The **period of index $i$** of a non-negative $\boldsymbol{A}\geq0$ is defined as $\varpi_{\boldsymbol{A}}(i):=\gcd\{m:\left[\boldsymbol{A}^{m}\right]_{ii}>0,m\in\mathbb{N}\}$. [One can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244639/period-of-index-i-of-a-matrix-and-irreducible-matrix) that for an irreducible $\boldsymbol{A}\geq0$ we have $\varpi_{\boldsymbol{A}}(i)=\varpi_{\boldsymbol{A}}(j), \forall i,j$. Therefore, this common value is simply called the **period** of an irreducible matrix,  $\varpi_{\boldsymbol{A}}$.

**Question.** Is it true that for any irreducible non-negative matrix  $\boldsymbol{A}\geq0$ we have  $\varpi_{\boldsymbol{A}}=h_{\boldsymbol{A}}$, that is, the period matches the number of dominant eigenvalues? How does one prove that?

I only know that for an irreducible $\boldsymbol{A}\geq0$,  we have $\varpi_{\boldsymbol{A}}=1$ ($\boldsymbol{A}$ is aperiodic) *iff* $h_{\boldsymbol{A}}=1$ ($\boldsymbol{A}$ is primitive) *iff* $\exists m:\boldsymbol{A}^m>0$ ($\boldsymbol{A}$ is eventually positive). This special case is easier to establish, and my question is about imprimitive non-negative irreducible matrices.

P.S. It looks like the question [Period of an irreducible Markov Chain is given by the number of eigenvalues with unit modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1751311/) is equivalent to mine, provided one shows that an irreducible non-negative matrix is (diagonally) similar to a Markov matrix. As neither of the questions has been answered, and since my phrasing is slightly more general, I propose not to flag duplicates, at least for now.

Comment: You can do this without Wielandt's Theorem, though that's probably the expedient route.  What's intuitive is going to depend a lot on background. If you are comfortable with modern algebra (at the level of Artin) then I have an essentially *algebraic* way to tease this out using some standard linear algebra combined with a sophisticated use of the trace.  I seem to also think there's a reasonably slick probabilistic approach (probably  doing this via renewal theory using ensemble averages), though the details are elusive.

Comment: @user8675309 Could you sketch the algebraic proof please? I am very curious about how the positivity enters the equation, in particular. I can't say I am comfortable with everything I see in Artin's Algebra, but many things feel familiar there, especially the standard _linear_ algebra part, so I'd give it a shot. Besides, the "sophisticated use of the trace" sounds very intriguing.

Comment: I have a writeup.  There are many parts but each is bite size.  It uses character theory  for one of the lemmas (Artin's *Group Representations* chapter is more than enough).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your questions is: **Yes**

A little bit of background, mainly based on [1, Chapter 3]. Irreducible, nonnegative matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are often associated with a graph $G(A)$ that has $n$ vertices and two vertices $i$ and $j$ are connected precisely if $[A]_{ij} > 0$. Then, the period of an irreducible matrix (as you define it) is precisely the gcd of the length of all cycles in $G(A)$. A theorem that directly states the connection that you are interested in, is [1, Theorem 3.18]

> **Theorem 3.18** Let $A$ be a nontrivial irreducible matrix with period $p$ and let $\lambda=\lambda(A)$. Then, there are exacty $p$ Eigenvalues $\mu$ of $A$ for which $|\mu|=\lambda$: those Eigenalues have the form $\lambda \omega^i$, where $\omega$ is a root of order $p$ of unity, and each of those Eigenvalues has algebraic multiplicity $1$.

The authors denote by $\lambda(A)$ the spectral radius of $A$. You might also be interested in [2, Corollary 8.4.7], which proves the statement in one direction.

[1] Marcus, Roth, Siegel - "Introduction to Coding for Constrained Systems", [https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~marcus/Handbook/](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Emarcus/Handbook/)
[2] Horn, Johnson - "Matrix Analysis"

Comment: If you are interested, I can try and compile some of the ideas needed to prove these statements. If I remember correctly, the main ingredient needed to prove these statements is a result from Wielandt https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WielandtsTheorem.html

Comment: I am fine with the statement and the proof of Theorem 3.18, **as long as** one replaces the period $p$ (which is $\varpi_\mathbb{A}$ in my notation) with  the index of imprimitivity $h_\mathbb{A}$. I saw this fact established in other books, e.g. in [Meyer], based on the Wielandt's theorem, exactly as you say. However, I haven't come across a text that explicitly states (let alone proves) the equality between the period and the index of imprimitivity. This is what I am struggling with.  


[Meyer]: Carl D. Meyer "Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra" http://matrixanalysis.com/

Comment: @paperskilltrees: The period $p$ is precisely $\varpi_{\boldsymbol{A}}$ in your notation, as you mention. And the theorem shows that this is the same as $h_{\boldsymbol{A}}$ by stating that there are exactly $p$ Eigenvalues on the spectral circle. I don't understand how this is different from the equality that you are seeking to prove.

Comment: This is indeed what I want to prove. But in the textbook you linked, the theorem is stated without a proof. I was just expressing a concern that a proof would go like _"Assume there are $p$ distinct eigenvalues on the spectral circle..."_, which I saw elsewhere and which would be unsatisfactory. But again, I haven't seen the proof yet.

Comment: Corollary 8.4.7 from the other text you cite [Horn&Johnson] looks interesting, but it seems to rely on Wielandt's theorem as well. I guess, Wielandt's theorem (Thm 8.4.5 in Horn&Johnson) is key in establishing that the period equals the number of eigenvalues on the spectral circle, and there is no way around it. Is there? Ideally, I would like to see a simpler and more direct relation between the two quantities, as Wielandt's theorem is not very tangible to me at this point. I need some time to process this; meanwhile, any clarification would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove this when the $A$ is mapped to a stochastic matrix, i.e. divide out the Perron root, and do the diagonal similarity transform here
[$\rho(B) \leq \rho(|B|)$, where $\rho$ is the spectral radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619228/rhob-leq-rhob-where-rho-is-the-spectral-radius)

The result is a matrix associated with an irreducible Markov chain.  Call this stochastic matrix $P$.

Note: when I say a Markov matrix can be written as a direct sum, technically what is meant is that up to graph isomorphism (i.e. permutation similarity) it is direct sum a / direct product / block diagonal.  $P^k$ being reducible for some $k$ alway implies block diagonal (as opposed to mere block triangular) since $P^k$ cannot have transient states since $P$ is irreducible (check e.g. $\pi P = \pi=\pi P^k$ and $\pi$ is a positive vector)

---

OP has already stated that the aperiodic case is understood--so that is taken for granted.  Note: aperiodicity is necessarily equivalent to there being only one eigenvalue on the unit circle.  Thus this proof starts only with the coarse association that $\geq 2$ eigenvalues on the unit circle for irreducible $P$ is equivalent to $P$ having some period $\geq 2$.

Let $P$ a stochastic matrix with index of imprimitivity $=r\geq 2$.  This means there are $r$ eigenvalues on the unit circle, only one of which $=1$ since $A$ is irreducible. The boundedness of $P$ (using e.g. Frobenius norm or operator 2 norm) implies these eigenvalues are all necessarily semi-simple (why?) and we'll prove they are in fact simple, forming a complete set of $r$th roots of unity.  For expediency, we write out the Jordan Form

$P = S\pmatrix{D_r & \mathbf 0\\\mathbf 0&J}S^{-1}$
where $D_r$ is a $r\times r$ diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues on the unit circle and $J$ contains Jordan blocks associated with eigenvalues strictly inside the unit circle.  We now put this aside for a bit and prove some lemmas.

**Lemma 1:**
Let $P$ be an irreducible $n\times n$ stochastic matrix with period $\geq 2$. Then $\text{trace}\big(P\big)=0$.

(The $n=1$ case trivially has trace one and is trivially aperiodic hence excluded).  For $n\geq 2$, by stochasticity we know $\text{trace}\big(P\big)\geq 0$, so *suppose for contradiction* that $\text{trace}\big(P\big)\gt 0$.  Then $P$ has exactly one $\lambda = 1$ (Perron root) and at least one other eigenvalue $\omega\neq 1$ which is on the unit circle (if no $\omega$ exists, then $\lim_{k\to\infty}P^k$ exists and $P$ is aperiodic).  Further $\text{trace}\big(P\big)\gt 0\implies$ at least one diagonal of $P$ that is positive, i.e. some $p_{j,j}\gt 0$. Then by applying (reverse) triangle inequality to row $j$ we see $\big(\omega I - P\big)$ is weakly diagonally dominant and irreducible, hence by Taussky's refinement of Gerschgorin Discs $\det\big(\omega I - P\big)\neq 0$ and $\omega$ is not an eigenvalue, a contradiction.  This proves the lemma.

(I gave a proof of Taussky's refinement under "optional second", here: [Prove that this block matrix is positive definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903369/prove-that-this-block-matrix-is-positive-definite/3904956#3904956) .)

**Lemma 2:**
all eigenvalues on the unit circle for irreducible $P$ are roots of unity (i.e. each satisfies $\lambda^k=1$ for some positive integer $k$).

If $P$ is aperiodic then the result is immediate.  Suppose $P$ is periodic.  We do this via strong induction on $n$.  The (Base) $2\times 2$ case: $P$ is stochastic and trace zero hence  $P= \pmatrix{0 & 1\\1&0}$

Inductive case:
We know $\text{trace}\big(P\big) =0$ but $\text{trace}\big(P^k\big) \gt 0$ for some minimal $k\in \big\{2,3,...,n\big\}$.  Note: $\text{trace}\big(P^k\big) \lt 0$ is impossible, and $\text{trace}\big(P^k\big) = 0$ for all $1\leq k \leq n$ powers implies $P$ is nilpotent which contradicts irreducibility.  Thus using the above minimal $k$, via Lemma 1 we know $P^k$ is reducible and/or aperiodic.  The former case explicitly says $P^k$ is reducible and we show it must be in the latter case as well.  If $P^k$ is aperiodic, all eigenvalues on the unit circle $=1$ which implies $\omega^k=1$ for some $\omega \neq 1$, and by Perron-Frobenius Theory $P^k$ is thus *reducible* into a collection of irreducible stochastic matrices, each of which has a single eigenvalue on the unit circle if aperiodic, and for period $\geq 2$ we may apply our induction hypothesis.  Thus each eigenvalue on the unit circle is a $k_i$th root of unity so $k':=k_1\cdot k_2\cdot ... \cdot k_r$ and they all satisfy $x^{k'}-1=0$.

**Lemma 3:**
Now consider the projection: $T = S\pmatrix{I_r & \mathbf 0\\\mathbf 0&\mathbf 0}S^{-1}$.  Then
$M:=TP=PT= S\pmatrix{D_r & \mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0&\mathbf 0}S^{-1}$
is a stochastic matrix.

Note that $T= \lim_{s\to \infty} \big(P^{k'}\big)^s$
which is a stochastic matrix and the product of two stochastic matrices is a stochastic matrix

**Lemma 4:**
$0 \leq \text{trace}\big(M^k\big) = \text{trace}\big(D_r^k\big)\leq r$

$M$ is a stochastic matrix hence $0\leq \text{trace}\big(M^k\big)$ and $\text{trace}\big(M^k\big) = \text{trace}\big(D_r^k\big)$ since $M$ and $D_r$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues.

By triangle inequality
$\text{trace}\big(M^k\big) =\text{trace}\big(D_r^k\big) = \big \vert \text{trace}\big(D_r^k\big) \big \vert  \leq \sum_{k=1}^r \vert d_{i,i}\vert^k = r$ with equality *iff* $D_r^k = I$.

**Lemma 5 (using character theory):**
(i) $\text{trace}\big(M^k\big) \in \big\{0,r\big\}$ for all $k$ and (ii) all non-zero eigenvalues of $M$ are distinct.

Let $G$ be the cyclic group generated by $D_r$.  Since this is already a matrix group then we may call $G'$ a  representation of $G$ via what amounts to the identity homomorphism.  I.e. $G'$ is a (faithful) $r$-dimensional representation of a finite abelian matrix group, $G$. Being abelian all irreducible representations are $1$-dimensional and the number of irreducible representations $=\vert G \vert$.  The character associated with $G'$, $\chi$, may be written as
$\chi = \eta_1 \cdot\chi_1+\eta_2\cdot \chi_2 + ... + \eta_{\vert G \vert}\cdot \chi_{\vert G \vert}= 1\cdot \chi_1+\eta_2 \cdot\chi_2 + ... + \eta_{\vert G \vert} \cdot\chi_{\vert G \vert}$
where $\eta_j \in \mathbb N$ (inclusive of zero).  (In terms of notation, page 319 of Artin's *Algebra* 1st edition could be useful here.)

We know the multiplicity of eigenvalue 1 for $G'$ (the trivial representation) is $1$.  Using the standard inner product for characters we have
$1=\langle \chi_1, \chi \rangle= \frac{1}{\vert G \vert}\sum_{k=1}^{\vert G\vert}1 \cdot \text{trace}\big(D_r^k\big)$

re-scaling by $r$ we have
$r= \frac{1}{\vert G \vert}\sum_{k=1}^{\vert G\vert}r \cdot \text{trace}\big(D_r^k\big)$
$\geq \frac{1}{\vert G \vert}\sum_{k=1}^{\vert G\vert} \text{trace}\big(D_r^k\big)\cdot \text{trace}\big(D_r^k\big)=\langle \chi, \chi\rangle = \eta_1^2+\eta_2^2 + ... + \eta_{\vert G \vert}^2$
$\geq \sum_{j=1}^{\vert G\vert} \eta_j=r$
The first inequality comes from the prior lemma and is met with equality *iff* $\text{trace}\big(D_r^k\big) \in \big\{0,r\big\}$ for all $k$ and the second inequality comes from the fact that $\eta_j \in \mathbb N$ and is met with equality *iff* all $\eta_j \in \big\{0,1\big\}$ i.e. if all eigenvalues of $D_r$ are distinct.

Since both inequalities are met with equality we conclude that all eigenvalues are distinct and $\text{trace}\big(M^k\big) \in \big\{0,r\big\}$ for all $k$

**Lemma 6:**
$D_r$ consists of a complete set of $r$th roots of unity.

Since $M$ is similar to $\pmatrix{D_r & \mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0&\mathbf 0}$ and all eigenvalues of $D_r$ are distinct, we know $M$ has minimal polynomial

$M^{r+1} + c_r M^r + c_{r-1}M^{r-1}+ ...+c_1 M=\mathbf 0$
i.e. $M^{r+1}$ is written uniquely as linear combination of $\big\{M^r, M^{r-1}, ..., M\big\}$.  Put differently,  $\big\{M^r, M^{r-1}, ..., M\big\}$ provides a basis for powers of $M$.  Since $\text{trace}\big(M^k\big)\gt 0$ for some $k$ ($M$ is not nilpotent), the above basis in combination with the Lemma $5$ implies
$\text{trace}\big(M^k\big)=r$ for some $k\in \big\{1,2,...,r\big\}$

Lemma $4$ tells us that $\text{trace}\big(M^k\big)=r\implies D_r^k = I_r \implies$ all eigenvalues of $D_r$ are $k$th roots of unity.  However for $k \in \big\{1,2,...,r-1\big\}$ there are $\lt r$ distinct kth roots of unity and all eigenvalues of $D_r$ are distinct by the lemma 5 $\implies \text{trace}\big(M^k\big)=0 $ for $k \in \big\{1,2,...,r-1\big\}\implies \text{trace}\big(M^r\big)=r\implies  D_r$ consists of a complete set of $r$th roots of unity.

**Corollary:**
$\text{trace}\big(M^k\big) = 0$ if $k\% r \neq 0$ (i.e. when $k$ is not a multiple of $r$)
$\text{trace}\big(M^k\big) = r$ when $k\% r = 0$  (i.e. when $k$ is a multiple of $r$)

**main problem:**
Suppose some diagonal element of $P^k$ is positive, then $\text{trace}\big(P^k\big)\gt 0$, and $P^k$ is reducible by the argument in Lemma 2 (in the induction case). So $P^k$ is a direct sum of $m=m_0+m_1$ irreducibles, where $m_0$ of those have period $p_i\geq 2$ each having trace zero by lemma 1, thus $\text{trace}\big(P^k\big)= $ sum of traces of $m_1$ aperiodic irreducibles (each having a single eigenvalue with modulus 1, i.e. the Perron root).
define $T':= \lim_{t\to \infty}\Big(\big(P^k\big)^{k^{''}}\Big)^t$
where mimicking before, $k^{''}$ is chosen to send all unit modulus eigenvalues of $\big(P^k\big)$ to 1.

When we apply $T'$, we get $\big(T'P^k\big)$ is *still* a direct sum of $m = m_0+m_1$ irreducibles
i.e. taking a power of $\big(P^k\big)$ respects the block diagonal structure it has (up to graph isomorphism) and this necessarily holds in limits as well.  When we examine an arbitrary block of $\big(P^k\big)$ we see that $T'$ kills all subdominant spectra but acts as the identity on roots of unity hence periodicity ($m_0$) and aperiodicity ($m_1$) is preserved.

but $T'=S\pmatrix{I_r & \mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0&\mathbf 0}S^{-1}=T$ thus

$T'P^k= TP^k = \big(TP\big)^k=M^k$ so
$ \text{trace}\big(M^k\big)=m_1\gt 0\implies k$ is a multiple of $r$ by the preceding corollary.  Finally $J^k\to \mathbf 0$ means $\big\vert \text{trace}\big(M^{r\cdot t}\big)- \text{trace}\big(P^{r\cdot t}\big)\big\vert\lt \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ for $t$ large enough, in particular after selecting $t$ we have $\text{trace}\big(P^{r\cdot t}\big)\gt 0$ and $\text{trace}\big(P^{r\cdot {(t+1)}}\big)\gt 0$ thus $r$ is the GCD.  We have established a bijection that $r$ eigenvalues on the unit circle for $P$ implies period $r$ for arbitrary integer $r\geq 2$ and this completes the proof.

Comment: note: the use of Jordan Form was for convenience.  A different route may be instructive.  First symmetrize Perron vector via similarity transform and call resulting matrix $C$ -- see end of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3863953/lambda-max-geq-n-for-a-positive-reciprocal-matrix/3864520#3864520.  This implies $C^TC$ has max eigenvalue $1$ so $\sigma_1=1$ for $C$.  Do Schur Triangularization:  $C=V\begin{bmatrix} T_r &  *\\ \mathbf 0 & Y \end{bmatrix}V^*$ where $T_r$ is upper triangular with $r$ eigenvalues on unit circle, and $Y$ has spectral radius $<1$.

Comment: Finally apply this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496086/proving-that-left-and-right-eigenvector-are-equal-using-singular-values/3496802#3496802 $r$ times, first to row 1, then row 2,...., then row $r$, and conclude $C=V\begin{bmatrix} D_r & \mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 & Y \end{bmatrix}V^*$.  This also tells you that eigenvalues on unit circle of $P$ must be semi-simple.